# C# Parse text file - access class field by index

Tags: c#

I'd like to parse a text file with a few dozen entries. Right now, I have a dumbed-down solution that reads line by line and compares against hard-coded strings:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) //returns null if end of stream
{
    cmpStr = "MODE";
    try
    {
        if (line.Equals(cmpStr))                        
            GlobalData.mode = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, cmpStr.Length));
    }
    catch { }

    cmpStr = "TIME_YEAR";
    try
    {
        if (line.Equals(cmpStr))                        
            GlobalData.time_year = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, cmpStr.Length));
    }
    catch { }


    // ... repeat to parse the remaining lines
}
```

GlobalData is a static class and looks like this:

```
public static class GlobalData
{

    public static int mode;                 
    public static int time_year;
    public static int time_month;
    public static int time_day;
    public static int time_hour;
    public static int time_minute;
    // other entries omitted

    public static string[] GlobalKeywords = new  string[37] 
    {
        "MODE", 
        "TIME_YEAR",
        "TIME_MONTH",
        "TIME_DAY",
        "TIME_HOUR",
        "TIME_MINUTE",
        // other entries omitted      
    };
}
```

If it were possible to access my static fields *by index*, I'd do:

```
int i = 0;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
    cmpStr = GlobalData.GlobalKeywords[i];    // when i == 0: cmpStr = "MODE"

    if (line.Equals(cmpStr))
        GlobalData[i] = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, cmpStr.Length));
        // GlobalData[0] would be GlobalData.mode, and so on (but doesn't work)

    i++;
}
catch { }
```

So, even though I can setup a loop to compare against a string array of keywords,
how do I assign a certain field of my static class ?

br
Chris

Comment: I am not sure how GlobalData[i] would be GlobalData.mode .

Comment: Can you show an example on how is formatted your input file?

Comment: You're right, that was missing. It's a .txt file where every entry is on a single line, and the lines are separated by CR+LF (Windows Linefeed). For example, the file could look like this: MODE 5<CR+LF>TIME_YEAR 2013<CR+LF>TIME_MONTH 10<CR+LF> etc.

Comment: @srsyogesh: That's exactly the point. I didn't want to introduce my 'C' way of thinking into the above C# source, but obviously did not succeed ;)

Comment: ok got it. I have explained below how you can do that in c#. May be if you are in need of this kind of behavior you can combine others answers with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your business constraints are, so it's hard to propose a fool-proof solution, though a few points:

> ```
> cmpStr = "MODE";
> try
> {
>    if (line.Equals(cmpStr))                        
>       GlobalData.mode = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, cmpStr.Length));
> }
> ```

This won't work as you (probably expect) - if `line.Equals("MODE")` then `line.Remove(0, "MODE".Length)` is an empty string. What you probably want is `line.StartsWith(cmpStr)` or `line.Contains(cmpStr)`.

> GlobalData is a static class

This doesn't seem a good approach for what you're doing. You may want to read up on static classes and when to use them (MSDN is a good starting point, though it obviously can't cover everything: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Other than that, you can probably simply replace all your int fields with a dictionary (though please rethink the static approach as described above):

```
public static Dictionary<String, int> Items = new Dictionary<String, int>();
```

Then your parsing code could look like this:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) //returns null if end of stream
{
   var matchingString
      = GlobalData.GlobalKeywords.FirstOrDefault(s => line.StartsWith(s));
   if (matchingString != null)
      GlobalData[matchingString]
           = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, matchingString.Length));
}
```

You will then be able to fetch that data using e.g. `GlobalData.Items["MODE"]`.

One last bit: you may consider introducing constant values in your global data class, e.g.:

```
public const String MODE = "MODE";
```

Then you can use `GlobalData.Items[GlobalData.MODE]` and avoid typos: writing `GlobalData.Items[GlobalData.MODe]` would cause a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
public static int mode;                 
public static int time_year;
public static int time_month;
public static int time_day;
public static int time_hour;
public static int time_minute;
```

With this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> my_values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then replace:

```
GlobalData[i] = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, cmpStr.Length));
```

with:

```
GlobalData.my_values[cmpStr] = Convert.ToInt32(line.Remove(0, cmpStr.Length));
```

That should do what you want even though I don't understand how you expect the `Convert.ToInt32` to work. The way you are calling `Remove` will create an empty string (which might convert to 0, I can't remember) and even if it didn't, the line doesn't contain a number because you compared it successfully to a string like "MODE".

Answer (score 1):

A simple (and not really clean) approach is to add an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to your global data class and decide which field to set based on the index. But you have to extend the indexer every time you add a field (basically you move the if/switch from the while Loop into the indexer).
You could also use reflection, if you can match the keyword to the field name. This is not very performant but does not need to be extended as long as you can map the keyword to the new field name.
Another approach is to create a dictionary>. In this dictionary you register the keywords, e.g. (pseudo-code):
Class Level variable:

```
private keywordsDict = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>();
```

In a constructor:

```
keywordsDict.Add("MODE", delegate(value) GlobalData.mode = value);
```

In while-loop:

```
var action = keywordsDict[line];
action(value);
```

In the later approach, you only need to extend the dictionary but not the algorithm as such if you have a new keyword/field.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to solve your problem is to prepare a different action for each of the acceptable strings. You use a `Dictionary(Of String, <Action>)` where Action is a common delegate type that receive a string in input and know how to process it accordingly to the keyword present at the beginning of the line.

```
// The common signature for every methods stored in the value part of the dictionary
public delegate void ParseLine(string line);

// Global dictionary where you store the strings as keyword
// and the ParseLine as the delegate to execute
Dictionary<String, ParseLine> m_Actions = new Dictionary<String, ParseLine>() ;

void Main()
{
    // Initialize the dictionary with the delegate corresponding to the strings keys
    m_Actions.Add("MODE", new ParseLine(Task1));
    m_Actions.Add("TIME_YEAR", new ParseLine(Task2));
    m_Actions.Add("TIME_MONTH", new ParseLine(Task3));
    m_Actions.Add("TIME_DAY", new ParseLine(Task4));
    .....

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        // Search the space that divide the keyword from the value on the same line
        string command = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' ')).Trim();
        // a bit of error checking here is required
        if(m_Actions.ContainsKey(command))
            m_Actions[command](line);

    }
}

void Task1(string line)
{
    // this will handle the MODE line
    GlobalData.Mode = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ')+1).Trim());

}
void Task2(string line)
{
     GlobalData.time_year = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ')+1).Trim());
}
void Task3(string line)
{
    .....
}
void Task4(string line)
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i can tell you how to achieve it (GlobalData[i]) in C# thought its not the answer you are looking for.

```
    class GlobalData
    {
        private string[] array = new string[10];
        public GlobalData()
        {
           //now initialize array
           array[0] = "SomeThingA";
           array[1] = "SomeThingB";//continue initialization.
        }
        public string this[int index]
        {
            get {return array[index];}
        }
    }
```

Now the clients can use GlobalData like ,

```
    GlobalData gd = new GlobalData();
    gd[1] = "SomeOtherThing" ; //set the value.
    string value = gd[1];//get the value
```

But this cant be done by making the class static as you see it works with **'this'**